# SpriteNode from class not rotating correctly in Scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, sprite-kit

I have a Class with a SpriteNode that rotates very wide, when rotated within the main Scene(as if the anchor point is in the middle of the screen and the Sprite is rotating around it). I want it to rotate around the anchor point of itself in the main Scene(anchor point on the Sprite).

So in the Class i have something like the following

```
- (void)createChainWithPos:(CGPoint)pos {
  SKTexture *myTex...
  SKTexture *myTex2...
  SKSpriteNode *chainFront = [SKSpriteNode spriteWithTexture:myTex];
  chainFront.position = pos;
  chainFront.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:mytex.size];
  [self addChild:chainFront];
  [_chainParts addObject:chainFront];

  SKSpriteNode *chainSide = [SKSpriteNode spriteWithTexture:myTex2];
  chainSide.position = CGPointMake(chainFront.position.x, chainFront.position.y - chainSide.size.height + 6);
  chainSide.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:myTex2.size;
  [self addChild:chainSide];
  [_chainParts addObject:chainSide];
}
```

I have an loop creating the chain parts in the main file but couldn't get it rotate so stripped it down in an new project. There is actually 4 chain parts but i only did two. The other two are just mirrors of the ones above with their positions mirroring the chainSide.(to position them in a chain like fashion)

and in the Scene

```
self.chain1 = [chain node];    
[self.chain1 createChainWithPos:CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
self.chain1.zRotation = 3.14/4;
[self addChild:self.chain1];
```

I have a NSMutableArray in the chain class header that i use to hold the chains.

the physics joints

```
for (int i = 1; i < self.chain1.chainParts.count; i++ {
    SKSpriteNode *nodeA = [[self.chain1 chainParts]objectAtindex:i-1];
    SKSpriteNode *nodeB = [[self.chain1 chainParts]objectAtindex:i];

    SKPhysicsJointPin *pin = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:nodeA.physicsBody
                                                         bodyB:nodeB.physicsBody
                                                        anchor:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(nodeA.frame), CGRectGetMinY(nodeA.Frame))];

}
```

I found that if i set the position of the chain in the middle in the Class, it rotates correctly in the Scene. However, the physics joints just start moving randomly across the screen and isn't  correct to the anchor points set. (the physics joints are set in the Scene)

I don't know if i have to convert the coordinates or play with random anchor point positions , but if someone could shed some light if would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use the nodes `frame`,  you want to use the nodes `size`,  the frame  mid is the screen coordinate + the fitted node size / 2, you want the middle of your sprite only, also for pi / 4  use `M_PI_4`

Comment: Ok I see... Will definitely try this out. Thanks for your help!